# How to change a bool into a string in an array

Tags: numpy

I tried to change a boolean array object into a string at printing process but it says that this object does not support variable assignments. I am new at numpy.

```
self.data=numpy.dtype([("Ad","S20"),("Yas","u1"),("Yasam","b")])
self.array=numpy.array([("Waluigi",40,True),("Wario",40,False)],dtype=self.data)
        for i in range(len(self.array)):

            i+=1

            if (self.array[i-1])[2]==True:
                 self.data[2]=("Yasam","S20")
                 (self.array[i-1])[2]="yasiyor"

            elif (self.array[i-1])[2]==False:
                 self.data[2]=("Yasam","S20")
                 (self.array[i-1])[2]="yasamiyor"
```

Comment: Please post the full error trace (not in the comments, update your post).

Comment: You defined that field as boolean.  You can't assign strings to it. Also when working with arrays like this, use the field name indexing.

Comment: For the `self.data[2]` assignment, the right size has to match the tuples used in defining the array,  `('string', 34, True)`.  Number and type of the elements in tuple matters.

Comment: And "b" does not mean boolean.  Check the `dtypes` again.  And look at `self.array` after  you create it.